# How do I correctly execute arguments in a shell script that have &&'s?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that I use while developing:

```
on_write nosetests
```

Will run nosetests everytime something changes in the file. However I have a lot of difficulty getting the following to work (it'll just run the first command):

```
on_write mvn test && mvn package
```

(I've got it working on another machine, but lost track of how to do it)

What I *really* would like is to insert an additional command after every && (like ogg123 --quiet drop.oga) but experiments with that aren't working well either.

```
on_write() {
  while inotifywait -q -q -e close_write -r .
  do
    clear
    "$@"
    ogg123 --quiet /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
  done
}
```

EDIT: A working version of this using

```
on_write "mvn test && mvn package"

on_write() {
        while inotifywait -qre close_write .
        do
                clear
                #eval "$@"
                eval "${@/&&/&& ogg123 --quiet /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga &&}"
                RETURN_VALUE=$?
                ogg123 --quiet /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
        done
        return $RETURN_VALUE
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using bash you could make use of eval:

```
on_write() {
  while inotifywait -q -q -e close_write -r .
  do
    clear
    eval "$@"
    ret=$?
    ogg123 --quiet /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
  done
  return $ret
}
```

and run it with:

```
on_write "mvn test && mvn package"
```

Comment: Thats what I was missing! Any idea how to substitute more stuff in for the &&'s?

Comment: depends, what are you looking for?

Comment: In the example "mvn test && mvn package" I'd like to change the "&&" to "&& ogg123 --quiet /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/drop.oga &&"

Basically if on_write receives a sequence of commands, it'll play a drip sound once each command finishes. I tried doing this with ${@/&&/stuff} but I kept getting bash errors instead, I'm not sure string substitution is intended for this case.

Comment: nm, I must have just been bad /w string replacement. I got it working now :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Each command in a command chain is executed separately.

```
on_write mvn test && on_write mvn package
```

Note that functions return the exit status of the last command executed, so you will have to save and return the appropriate one.

```
on_write() {
  while inotifywait -q -q -e close_write -r .
  do
    clear
    "$@"
    ret=$?
    ogg123 --quiet /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
  done
  return $ret
}
```